# How to use next() inside the for loop in java for getting next resultset

Tags: java, prepared-statement, resultset

I am want to take id of each no which are presented in the array constant. Please find the below code. When i am running this i am getting    "ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next." error. but 101 working correctly. rest of the values or not fetched. Please anyone help me

```
 PreparedStatement m_inoutid = null;
 docno="[101,102,103,104]";
 String minoutid[]=new String[1000];
 String documentno = docno.substring(1, docno.length() - 1);
 List<String> docnumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
 String[] split = documentno.split(",");
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

  String sql = "select id from mytable where fid=?";

   outid = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   String  idfromquery=split[i];
    outid.setString(1, idfromquery);
    ResultSet idResultSet = outid.executeQuery();
    idResultSet.next();

    id = idResultSet.getString("id");

   final List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<Object>();
   parameters.add(null);
   parameters.add(id);

   myfunction(parameters);
    }
```

Comment: you may want to check that you got results before you obtain the 'id' - something like 
`while ( idResultSet.next() ) { 
   // Read the next item
   idResultSet.getString("id");
}`

Comment: Close the resultSet and preparedStatement after reading value.

Comment: i have closed the resultset and prepared statement . but  it is not working .Error remain same. @Syam

Comment: I tried your code. Its working fine even without closing. Which database are you using?

Comment: Values are correctly printing @blurfus. Please help me..

Comment: I am using POSTGREY SQL database..

Comment: First value is working correctly but rest of the values not working. The exception remain same

Comment: consider moving `String sql = "select id from mytable where fid=?";` and `outid = conn.prepareStatement(sql);` outside the loop

Comment: i placed those things outside the loop. but error remain same. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I can see here two things that you might try:

1. You can check if all of your queries return at least one row. Maybe there is an ID you pass to the query that does not validate the WHERE clause for any of the results. You can check this by placing the call to `next` in a conditional statement like

   `if(idresultSet.next()) id = idResultSet.getString("id");`
2. Additionally, maybe you should try to place the cursor to the first row (just to be sure) after executing the query. Like

   `ResultSet idResultSet = outid.executeQuery();
   idResultSet.first();
   idResultSet.next();`

Comment: query always return one row. I will try second solution and let you know.

Comment: Operation requires a scrollable ResultSet, but this ResultSet is FORWARD_ONLY. This error is i am getting when i am trying second solution